# SharePoint Online site restore after 15 days of deletion

Tags: sharepoint-online, restore

We have a scenario that we lost some data and now we want to restore the SP online site collection. I.e., we lost data on 15 days back. Due to some reason, now we want to bring back the site using Point In Time Restore. Is it possible to restore the site collection, after 15 days of deletion. MS says they will retain 14 days of daily backup. In my scenario, as per MS, 15 days crossed. So it is possible to restore?

Answer (score 2):

Deleted SharePoint sites are retained for **93 days**, not 15 days. After 93 days, sites and all their content and settings are permanently deleted, including lists, libraries, pages, and any subsites. About how to restore a deleted site in the new SharePoint admin center, please refer to the following URL: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/restore-deleted-site-collection

Comment: Thanks Allen. We have NOT deleted site. Only SP security groups and its assigned permission to documents are deleted. So we want to restore the site completely.

Answer (score 2):

Restoring a site that belongs to a Microsoft 365 group restores the Microsoft 365 group and all its resources.

> **Note** that the other group resources are retained for only 30 days, whereas the site is retained for 93 days.

Comment: This is not office 365 group. Its SP security groups. We have NOT deleted site. Only SP security groups and its assigned permission to documents are gone. So we want to restore the site completely. Groups deleted 15 days back.

Answer (score 1):

In this case it isn't possible to restore as security groups are not retained in the site recycle bin. You would have needed to contact Microsoft prior to the 14 day time frame.

Comment: Yes, we contacted Microsft but due to some reason, it crossed 14 days. Now is there way ?

Comment: Since you don't personally have a backup, no there is no way to restore that data.